# Should CRUD methods be part of the object or a service layer?

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I was going through some object oriented design problems for learning and I came across this problem where a Book object is needed in a book catalog. This is the Book object that is suggested in the solution to the problem.

```
public class Book {

    private long ID;
    private String details; 
    private static Set<Book> books;

    public Book(long iD, String details) { ... }    

    public static void addBook(long iD, String details){
        books.add(new Book(iD, details));
    }

    public void update() { }

    public static void delete(Book b) { books.remove(b); }

    public static Book find(long id){
        for (Book b : books)        
            if(b.getID() == id) return b;   
        return null;

    }
}
```

In one way this `Book` object looked quite good to me since it contains all the methods that are needed to modify/get info about the book object as well as the data about the book. So when going with the definition of OOP this looks great since that is what an object should be.

But the way I had been doing stuff in my 1-2 years of programming career I always thought that creating, deleting. modifying an object should be done via a service layer, essentially a BookService class in this case which contains methods to create Books, update books and delete books from the database using the Book object which doesn't contain these CRUD methods.

The first approach looks great in theory while the next one is great in practice as I know from whatever experience I have. Are there flaws/pitfalls of the second approach? Which approach should be preferred ?

*PS: I am not sure if such questions are accepted and I would gladly delete/edit it if they aren't but I don't find a better place to get the answer :(*

Comment: I'd expect an `update()` method on a `Book` to update the `Book` object that's stored in memory in your program--_but not an object in the database_.  Unless you name your class so that it's clear that it refers to a book _in that particular database_ (or in some abstract database), the `Book` should be independent of any database or other source that it comes from, and its methods shouldn't know anything about the database.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for the response. If I understood it right you are saying that the above book object will serve the purpose of updating books/fetching or deleting books from memory but not from the database. In other words in a real application this logic should be in the Service classes instead of in the book object?

Comment: What I mean is that the `Book` object holds information about the book, and not about any larger collection of books that contains the book, whether it's a Java `Collection`, a database, or some other data structure.  So any update methods should be just about updating that information, not about doing anything that affects the containing structure.  For a `List<Book>`, nothing else would need to be done anyway.  But consider a `HashMap<Book>` where the book title is the key, and you update the book title.  Updating the `Book` won't fix the `HashMap` which will now be wrong...

Comment: ...so this really isn't about whether the "collection" is in memory or not; it's about defining what the purpose of your class is.  Sorry if my first comment confused you about the "memory" thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are implementing a console application with study purpose, it`s not a big deal if you implement CRUD logic into the model..but i do not think that this is the case.

This model Book which you have implemented must have only object properties plus getter and setters. The other CRUD methods which you implemented must be in a external layer. A external layer may be a SERVICE or a DAO, it depends.. But you have to know that it is not a good practice if you write some extra logic in model classes like now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I understood it right the second approach i.e Service layer approach is the way to go. The Book object in the question above is one in the book I was reading. I guess the book is being a bit simplistic in order to explain OOP design but in a real scenario that is not the way to go. Am I right?

Comment: @varunkr yeah, this is the correct way for implementation. The book can be a little simplistic but it`s not a problem to follow the book guide. But anyway, you will learn this techniques if you continue to do programming.

Comment: @varunkr If my post helped you, mark it as a answer please.

Answer (score 5):

Your `Book` object is a so-called "domain object". Its only responsibility is to provide the so-called "business logic". E.g: it has a state, defined by the class members, and it can contain class methods (for calculations, etc) to interact with the state. No other objects should know about the internal business logic implementation.

Now, the domain objects are also known as "models". But that can be a bit confusing. Why? Because a "model" is actually a layer. And it is composed of three sublayers:

- The **[domain layer (domain model)](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html)**, consisting of the domain
  objects. Through their structure and interdependence with each other,
  they are the abstraction of the real world (business)
  objects/entities. This layer could also contain structures like
  collections of domain objects.
- The **storage layer**, composed from the classes responsible with the
  transfer of the domain objects into/from the underlying storage
  system (may it be RDBMS, file system etc): [repositories](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), [(data)
  mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), [adapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), data-access abstraction classes, etc. The
  use of these structures also achieve the purpose of making the domain
  objects (completely) agnostic, unaware of the storage type and the
  way in which it is addressed.
- The **[service layer](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)** is built from classes (e.g. services) that
  execute operations involving the structures from the upper two
  sublayers. The user interaction with the program should take place
  only through services.

So, in your case, the domain object `Book` would look like this:

```
public class Book {

    private long ID;
    private String details;

    public Book() { ... }

    // Setters/getters...
}
```

Then you'd have a data mapper (`BookDataMapper`) as well:

```
public class BookDataMapper {

    private DbAdapter adapter;
    private Set<Book> books;

    public BookDataMapper(DbAdapter adapter) {
        // Assign DbAdapter object to the adapter class member.
    }    

    public void select(long bookId) {
        // 1. Fetch book record from db by bookId and using the injected db adapter.
        // 2. Map fetched db record to a Book object using mapBook().
        // 3. Add Book object to books using addBook().
    }
    public void insert(Book book) {
        // 1. Read the class members of object book.
        // 2. Inject the values in an INSERT SQL statement as parameters.
        // 3. Run the INSERT query and return last insert id.
        // 4. Assign the last insert id to book's ID class member. 
        // 4. Return book.
    }
    public void update(Book book) { ... }
    public void delete(Book book) { ... }

    public void mapBook(array bookRecord){
        // 1. Create a plain Book object.
        // 2. Read bookRecord array and map each field to the corresponding 
        //    class member of the Book object.
        // 3. Return mapped Book object.
    }

    public void addBook(Book book){
        // Add book to books collection.
    }

}
```

You could define a higher layer of abstraction for the data access as well, e.g. a `BookRepository`. You can/should also move the book collection (code) inside it:

```
public class BookRepository {

    private BookDataMapper bookMapper;

    public BookRepository(BookDataMapper bookMapper) {
        // Assign BookDataMapper object to the bookMapper class member.
    }    

    public void find(long bookId) {
        // 1. Use bookMapper to fetch book record from the storage by bookId.
        //    Notice that I said storage, not db: per definition, a repository 
        //    hides the details regarding the storage type. The user (client) 
        //    knows only that the book is placed... somewhere.
        // 2. Return the fetched book object.
    }
    public void store(Book book) {
        // 1. Use bookMapper to store the book.
        // 2. Return the book (with last insert id in it).
    }
    public void update(Book book) { ... }
    public void remove(Book book) { ... }

}
```

And at last, define a service (`BookBorrowingService`) to manage the book borrowing process when a user wants to borrow a book from the library:

```
public class BookBorrowingService {

    private UserCardRepository userCardRepository;
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookBorrowingService(UserCardRepository userCardRepository, BookRepository bookRepository) {
        // 1. Assign UserCardRepository object to the userCardRepository class member.
        // 2. Assign BookRepository object to the bookRepository class member.
    }    

    public void borrowBook(long userCardId, long bookId) {
        // 1. Use userCardRepository and the given card id to find the user card.
        // 2. Validate the card based on its details. If successfull go further.
        //    If not, then return corresonding response to user.
        // 3. Use bookRepository and the given book id to find the book.
        // 4. Return the fetched book object.
    }

}
```

Then, in the main part bind all pieces together:

```
// Create and share db connection(s).
// Create and share adapter(s).
// Create mappers.
// Create repositories.
BookBorrowingService bookBorrowingService = new BookBorrowingService(userCardRepository, bookRepository);
Book book = borrowBook(123, 4567890);
```

To answer to your **question(s)**:

The advantage of structuring your code in this way is, that each class has very good delimited responsibilities, conforming to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). For example, a domain object's responsibility should only be business logic, not data access. So, in short, this [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principle contradicts your first approach. You can also say that a [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) take place.

The only disadvantage of using the described approach is only that you'll have to write more code.

**Notes:**

- I don't program in Java. That's why I didn't implemented more code.
- Use a dependency injection container.
- Forget about statics, globals, singletons.
- Use interfaces instead of concrete implementations.

Good luck!

Comment: For the users who downvote(d) my question: Please let me know the motive(s) of your downvotes, so that I can change my answer correspondingly. This way we can contribute together to the continuous improvement of this website. Thank you.

Comment: Hey thnx for the answer. I am not sure who downvoted it.

Comment: @varunkr You are very welcome. Don't worry about the downvote. It's not relevant for me anyway, as long as it wasn't motivated in words.